# mysql on xp performance issues

Tags: mysql, windows-xp

Please could you let me know if there are any performance issues with using mysql on windows xp. The mysql serves over 10 client server apps, which query the database simultaneously

Comment: This is really not enough. You should not have issues with 10 client apps, unless either the design is incorrect, or you have data dating back to 2000BC

Comment: XP is a desktop OS, not a server OS.  I'd use the setup for a test instance, but not a live, production instance...  I can't remember the limitations, but there were some that MS supposedly did after the NT hack to get a server level OS iirc...

Answer (score 0):

Generally I run MySQL on Windows Server 2003 with Dual or Quad core processors -> unless I have too much data or a bad index/query the MySQL database has no issue with 50+ client apps.

On XP I don't find that much of an issue - generally a desktop has lower horsepower and isn't optimized for MySQL speed.

I would recommend the book [High Performance MySQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003067/) if you want more answers on getting MySQL to run optimally.